# How to fix the conflict when push change to two repos at the same time and one get conflict

Tags: git

I have a repository with config file likes below:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@bitbucket.org:abc/abc.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        pushurl = https://github.com/abc/abc-mirror
        pushurl = git@bitbucket.org:abc/abc.git
```

github's repo is a mirror of the bitbucket's. I made some change to github's and push it to github's only. I also made some change on bitbucket's and when I push the change, there is a conflict with github's repo but no problem with bitbucket's.

In this case, how can I fetch the github's change and resolve the conflict?

I believe my question probably be asked somewhere on SO but I cannot find one. Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're making separate changes to the Bitbucket version it isn't a mirror. That seems problematic. Maybe back up and explain what problem you're solving with this setup? And why you had to make a change to the "mirror"?

Comment: @Schwern My workplace blocks bitbucket but has no issue with github. Thus, I want to have a mirror repo on github so that I can keep changes while I'm at work. I also like whatever I change on github's repo also goes to the bitbucket's repo easily. I think you're right. I messed up the mirror stuff.

Comment: Just add a second remote to fetch from github.

Comment: @o11c could you please list out the exact line change? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> *My workplace blocks bitbucket but has no issue with github.*

There's two ways to deal with this.

Simplest is social: ask IT to whitelist Bitbucket. They probably aren't deliberately blocking it. Either they're using a whitelist and it's not on it, or some overzealous blacklist found something it thinks is naughty in some Bitbucket repository and blacklisted the whole domain.

Since there's an unfortunately high chance of that not happening, the technical fix is to go through the firewall with a [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) or [SSH tunnel](https://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html). The VPN is simplest and is very useful for many situations. The SSH tunnel requires you to run an ssh server outside the firewall. Though if IT is really overzealous they'll have blocked VPNs and outgoing SSH as well.

Finally, if you can use your mobile phone as a hotspot, you can use its internet connection.

> *Thus, I want to have a mirror repo on github so that I can keep
>   changes while I'm at work. I also like whatever I change on github's
>   repo also goes to the bitbucket's repo easily. I think you're right. I
>   messed up the mirror stuff.*

If you make changes to both they will "diverge". This is a manageable situation, but you'd have to manage them as separate remotes. That doesn't seem necessary for your situation.

Instead, decide which one is the mirror and stick with it. It sounds like you prefer Bitbucket, so use Github as the mirror. Rather than having two pushurls, set up Bitbucket as the `pushurl` and Github as the `mirror`. Then when you `push` whatever is on Github will be overwritten with your local version.

[From the git-push docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)...

> --mirror
>
> Instead of naming each ref to push, specifies that all refs under refs/ (which
>              includes but is not limited to refs/heads/, refs/remotes/, and refs/tags/) be
>              mirrored to the remote repository. Newly created local refs will be pushed to
>              the remote end, locally updated refs will be force updated on the remote end,
>              and deleted refs will be removed from the remote end. ***This is the default if
>              the configuration option remote.<remote>.mirror is set.***

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. From the answer, it seems I can only do the modification to bitbucket's repo and whatever change I made on github's will get overridden? Is there anyway to merge the changes given my setting without doing it in the hardest way ...

Answer (score 0):

For the immediate case, add a remote

```
git remote add github https://github.com/abc/abc-mirror
```

Then use `git fetch github`, followed by any of the usual conflict resolution techniques (`git merge github/master` or `git rebase github/master`). You could do it in one step with appropriate arguments to `git pull`, but I find doing each step separately is far easier.

---

For the long term ... I think the best way to do mirrors (or builds, etc) is to have some server with a cronjob doing `git fetch github && git push bitbucket` in a bare repo ... or possibly use github's notification hooks, but I never bothered since I didn't care about immediacy and waiting an hour between syncs was acceptable for my use case.

It's also not clear why you're treating bitbucket as the primary here, since github is the only one that can be updated on its own.